# Grouping to get smallest amount of groups by a summation of values

Tags: java, arrays

I have a collection of objects, lets just say Files, and I would like to group them by a maximum total size of the files in a group. But I would like to find the smallest number groups posible.

Now lets say that the List of object looks like this

```
class FileSize{
    int size;
    public FileSize(int size){
        this.size=size;
    }
}
private void test(){
    List<FileSize> files = new ArrayList<FileSize>();
    files.add(new FileSize(4));
    files.add(new FileSize(6));
    files.add(new FileSize(10));
    files.add(new FileSize(3));
    files.add(new FileSize(2));
    files.add(new FileSize(15));
    files.add(new FileSize(12));
    files.add(new FileSize(1));
    files.add(new FileSize(7));
}
```

And that I would like to have groups by with the accummulated size = 20. Now the above would give 3 groups with 20 in each.

Now I know that functions like [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) exist but it seems like only accumulating over other values.

Does a method for this kind of grouping already exist?

Answer (score 0):

In standard Java API there is no such method that would do the job for you. You may search on internet if anyone provides any library that does such a thing, but I doubt it. Unless you find some existing library you will have to write the solution on your own

Comment: Problems like this one are not uncommon, so it’s quite possible a web search will turn up something. Happy searching. Or coding, if it turns out that way.